# Persistent layout in Next.js with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want add a persistent layout to certain pages, but I have problems to set `PageName.layout = BaseLayout`.

Already set type to `_app` file (code below):

```
// page.d.ts file
import { NextPage } from 'next';
import { ComponentType } from 'react';

export type Page<P = {}> = NextPage<P> & {
    layout?: ComponentType;
};

// custom app props
import { AppProps } from 'next/app';

export type AppCustomProps = AppProps & {
    Component: Page;
};


// _app.tsx file
const MyApp: NextPage<AppCustomProps> = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
    const Layout = Component.layout || EmptyLayout;

    return (
        <ThemeProvider>
            {/* SVG Sprite */}
            <ProjectIcons />
            <Layout>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
};

export default MyApp;
```

But the problem is in pages, for example, in Home page I have 2 props:

```js
type Home = {
    allEpisodes: IFormattedEpisode[];
    latestEpisodes: IFormattedEpisode[];
};

const Home: NextPage<Home> = ({ allEpisodes, latestEpisodes }) => {...}
```

How to add the layout prop in my page?
Already try the `Home.layout` but not working.

Comment: Already solved thanks.
But I have one problem.
I want if my API return a null value render the 404 component, but for that case I need the empty layout.
How can do that?